# Is there any way to deploy a web deploy package on IIS in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-applications

How can I deploy my web deploy package on IIS with c# code?I want to have a console application that deploy package on IIs.

Comment: Why you need an executable to deploy the service if you already have a installer created?

Comment: @Kurubaran I want in post build event run my app and deploy my app on IIS

Comment: Isn't it just run msbuild -> copy files to IIS dir?